# What does Adjudicator mean, "Both from above and below"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, john-wick-chapter-3-parabellum

In [John Wick: Chapter 3 – Parabellum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wick:_Chapter_3_%E2%80%93_Parabellum), Adjudicator says to Winston about John Wick:

> I trust you understand the repercussions if he survives.  **Both from
>   above and below**. The last thing either one of us needs is Mr. wick
>   paying us a visit in the night.

What does Adjudicator mean, "Both from above and below"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She's referring to hierarchy.

If John survive they both will be punished by the High Table. This is repercission from above.

The one from below would be that night visit. Adjudicator is very classist. She acknowledge he is an exceptional assassin but he is, to her, still someone less than her.

And failing to kill John might send a message to every other assassin and people using their services that you might try to fight Adjucators, rules of Continental and maybe even High Table.